# Reducing CPU usage of navigator.webkitGetUserMedia (Electron: DesktopCapturer)

Tags: webkit, cpu-usage, electron, getusermedia, navigator

I'm using `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia` to capture screenshot of a window once every second by assigning the returned `stream` to a `<video>` and copying it to a `<canvas>` and saving the Buffer to file.

The CPU usage in my application is consistently high and I've pinpointed it to this area.

## Code

```
// Initialize the video, canvas, and ctx
var localStream,
  _video = document.querySelector('#video'),
  _canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas'),
  _ctx = _canvas.getContext('2d'),
  sourceName = 'my-window-id';

// Load the stream from navigator.webkitGetUserMedia
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
  audio: false,
  video: {
    mandatory: {
      chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
      chromeMediaSourceId: sourceName,
      minWidth: 1920,
      maxWidth: 1920,
      minHeight: 1080,
      maxHeight: 1080
    }
  }
}, gotStream, getUserMediaError);

function gotStream(stream) {
  // Use the stream in our <video>
  _video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

  // Reference the stream locally
  localStream = stream;
}

function captureState() {
  var buffer,
    dataURL;

  // Draw <video> to <canvas> and convert to buffer (image data)
  _ctx.drawImage(_video, 0, 0);
  dataURL = _canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  buffer = new Buffer(dataURL.split(",")[1], 'base64');

  // Create an image from the data
  fs.writeFileSync('screenshot.png', buffer);
}

// Capture state every second
setInterval(function() {
  captureState();
}, 1000);
```

This code my not run, it's a simplified version of what I have in my code to make it StackOverflow readable.

## Things I've Tried

1. `_video.pause()` and `_video.play()` when needed. Didn't seem to change CPU usage.
2. `_video.stop()`. This means I would have to get the stream again which causes a spike in CPU usage worse than keeping it open.

My best lead right now is to change the frame rate by adding:

```
  optional: [
    { minFrameRate: 1 },
    { frameRate: 1 }
  ]
```

Extremely low frame rate would be fine. However, I haven't been able to determine if the `frameRate` setting works in this case. [The docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) don't have it listed and I don't have the newer `mediaDevices.getUserMedia` available.

Is it possible to set extremely low frame rates (or any at all) for `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia`?

Has anyone been able to reduce CPU usage of the stream in any other way?

Any alternative methods of achieving the same goal (state capture on interval) would also be helpful.

Thanks!

**Side Note**

This is in an Electron app on Windows using [DesktopCapturer](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/desktop-capturer.md) to get the `chromeMediaSourceId`.

---

**Update on CPU Usage**

1. Cost of running `stream`: 6% CPU Usage
2. Calling `captureState` every 1000ms: 5% CPU Usage

Total Current: 11%

Currently working on reducing #2 based on the recommendations of Csaba Toth so far. I should be able to reduce `captureState` by changing how the canvas is captured. Will update when that's done.

For #1, if I can't avoid capturing the video stream I'll have to just try to cap the total CPU usage at just over 6% by optimizing #2.

Comment: What type of CPU do you have? 6% + 5% is not necessarily too bad IMHO. If it's 6-8 cores, that'd consume one core completely though. Do not expect to eliminate #2 completely. Maybe it's a good idea to see if it's possible to screenshot without video stream.

Comment: i5-6500. No it's not terrible, it seems to be operating alright now. I was using multiple streams before for another reason but found a workaround and now only need the one stream. If I can get it to stay below 10% I'll be happy, I think your sugestions below should get me there.

Answer (score 1):

There's some unnecessary base64 encoding and operations going on here, it's weird how you get hold of the data:

```
dataURL = _canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
buffer = new Buffer(dataURL.split(",")[1], 'base64');
```

Take a look at how the QR decoder access the image instead: https://github.com/bulldogearthday/booths/blob/master/scripts/qrdecoder.js#L1991

```
var canvas_qr = document.getElementById("qr-canvas");
var context = canvas_qr.getContext('2d');
qrcode.width = canvas_qr.width;
qrcode.height = canvas_qr.height;
qrcode.imagedata = context.getImageData(0, 0, qrcode.width, qrcode.height);
```

(the other side of the software did a `drawImage` to the canvas earlier). Now the task would be to find a method which won't unnecessarily convert the PNG data into base64 and then decode it. I see that everywhere this URI encoding is advised because it's less number of lines. But performance wise an unecessary encoding/decoding phase is undesirable. 1920x1080 PNGs are big, not meant for base64 in-lining. Since you are in nodejs anyway, try to use https://github.com/niegowski/node-pngjs or similar library to save the image data.

There's always a tradeoff between space and time, so if time really matters with lower compression you can have higher performance: https://github.com/wheany/js-png-encoder

There is a trade-off here, since the base64 URI encoding examples take advantage of the browser's native (C++, fast) png encoding, but then do unnecessary base64 encodeing+decoding. The node-pngjs would perform PNG encoding in JS land, which *maybe* not as performant as the browser's internal encoding. The best would be to find a way to leverage the browser's encoding without having the base64.

---

*Earlier advices*

According to what you show I think your main problem is that you perform `_ctx.drawImage(_video, 0, 0);` and other operations in your `gotStream`.

Here is a Progressive Web App of mine, it performs QR code scanning too: https://github.com/bulldogearthday/booths/blob/master/scripts/app.js
Notice that in the "`gotStream`" (which is anonymous in my case https://github.com/bulldogearthday/booths/blob/master/scripts/app.js#L67) I only wire up the stream to the canvas.

My situation is easier because I don't have to enforce size (I hope you dont' hard wire those screen size pixel numbers), but I also perform processing (QR code scan attempt, every 500ms) periodically. I originally used timer for that, but that stopped working after a some iterations/ticks, so technically I issue a single timeout, and every time it hits I re-issue a new one. See initial timeout https://github.com/bulldogearthday/booths/blob/master/scripts/app.js#L209 and periodical re-issue: https://github.com/bulldogearthday/booths/blob/master/scripts/app.js#L231

As you can see the only place I do "heavy lifting" is in the `app.scanQRCode` which happens only twice a second. There I process the content of the canvas:
https://github.com/bulldogearthday/booths/blob/master/scripts/app.js#L218

I advise you to restructure your code that way. So setup either a timer ticking every second or re-issue time-outs as me. Then do the capture+save in that section. Hopefully that will lighten the CPU load, although encoding 1920x1080 `PNG` once a second may stress a CPU (there will be `PNG` encoding).

(That's beneficial if you want to go for individual images. If you want to end-up with a video anyway in the end, then I'd try to go on the route of enforcing 1s FPS video as you suggested and capturing the video stream directly instead of individual images. But for the CPU load my suggestion should help IMHO.)

---

In the README (https://github.com/bulldogearthday/booths) you can see one of the main sources I looked at for `getUserMedia`: https://github.com/samdutton/simpl/blob/gh-pages/getusermedia/sources/js/main.js

I don't fiddle with issuing `.play()` or `.pause()` or anything. As a matter of fact my code waits until it receives the signal that the play started (starts by itself by default at least for cameras): `document.getElementById('qrVideo').addEventListener('playing', app.saveVideoSize, false);` https://github.com/bulldogearthday/booths/blob/master/scripts/app.js#L67 My intention with that was to not disturb the natural process with anything if possible. In my case I detect the video size this gentle way. Looking at DesktopCapturer they also don't perform any extra in the `gotStream` in their README https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/desktop-capturer.md, and as shown ideally you just wire up the video stream with the canvas.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough post! My code is actually separated as you suggested--grabs the stream and saves it, calling a separate `captureState` on interval. I've updated my code to reflect this. Just reading through the rest of your code now.

Comment: So the only difference I see is that you're grabbing the canvas context each time you need it rather than keeping a reference to the context as I have in `_ctx`. I'll give that a try and see if there is any change.

Comment: When you talk about capturing the video stream directly, how would I go about doing that? I need to be able to do image comparison and I assumed `canvas` rendered in this way was the only way to accomplish that.

Comment: @Matt If you need to do image comparison then it doesn't make sense to capture video stream.

Comment: @Matt: added some new insights

Comment: I'm going to try what you suggested about the image processing. If that works my only barrier is the stream as my CPU usage breakdown now shows above. 6% usage certainly isn't the end of the world.